# How to create a fake ActiveRecord object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

How can I create a fake, but realistic, fullfiled ActiveRecord instance?

For example, if I have the model Contract.rb with properties like name (String), created_at (Date), and id (Integer), what should a method do that returns an instance of Contract with all properties set with fake but realistic values?

I know about the excellent gem faker, but I want all properties of Contract.rb to be all filled dynamically, with the appropriate type.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What are you trying to do this for? Are you trying to test some instance method of the `Contract` object, but wanting to avoid actually hitting the database?

Comment: I want, by default, a correct fulfilled object. Each time I change/add a property, I don't want to update accordingly my factories and test.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [**`FactoryGirl`**](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot_rails) with [**`Faker`**](https://github.com/stympy/faker) to achieve this.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user, class: User do
    email { Faker::Internet.email }
    password 'password'
    password_confirmation { password }
  end
end
```

FactoryGirl gem will help you to create the records with the values from Faker gem

> NOTE: As mentioned by @stefan `FactoryGirl` is officially renamed to `FactoryBot`.

Comment: The library was renamed to "Factory Bot" in October.

Comment: Then I start searching why they renamed it :D

Comment: See [Project Naming History](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/NAME.md) and the corresponding [blog post](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/factory_bot)

Comment: Huhh.. so the name was offensive

Answer (score 0):

You have to write own method to fill all fields of contract.rb

you can either use [faker](https://github.com/stympy/faker) or [forgery](https://github.com/sevenwire/forgery) gems.

often people use these gems to seed their datbase with fake records or for generating test suites.

We used forgery gem with factory girl to seed our databse with 1M dummy records.